# dwr addoptions with associative array

Tags: javascript, dwr

I have an associative array.I want to be able to add the options to a dropdown using the associative array key as value to option and array key as text of option element.

```
 var associativeArray = new Array();
 associativeArray['city'] = "Portland";
 associativeArray['state'] = "Oregon";
 associativeArray['country'] = "United States";
 dwr.util.addOptions(makeId3.id,associativeArray);
```

Doing the above creates options elements with text and value as :

```
<option value="city,Portland">city,Portland</option>
```

However I am expecting the following:

```
<option value="city">Portland</option>
```

How can I achieve the above with dwr and associative arrays.Could anyone suggest?

Comment: In Javascript you should use an object for an associative array, not an array.

Answer (score 1):

Use an object rather than an array:

```
var associativeArray = {
    city: "Portland",
    state: "Oregon",
    country: "United States"
};
dwr.util.addOptions(makeId3.id, associativeArray, false);
```

Or if you want to add the properties dynamically, use:

```
var associativeArray = {};
associativeArray['city'] = "Portland";
associativeArray['state'] = "Oregon";
associativeArray['country'] = "United States";
```

See the [documentation](http://directwebremoting.org/dwr/documentation/browser/util/addOptions.html). It treats an array argument differently from an object.